# Create a timer to go through images

Tags: javascript, html, image, timer

Using Javascript and HTML I need to create a timer to display the pictures every 3 seconds.  I need to use the array to do this and keep the onclick available.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title> Image Swapping</title>

        <div id=getPhoto></div>
        <script>
            var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", image4.jpg"];
            function changeImage(newImage) {
                var image = images[newImage];
                newImage = document.getElementById("bigPic");
                newImage.src = image;
            }
            var myTimer = setInterval(chose(), 3000);
            var divVariable = document.getElementById("images");
            function chose(){
                var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * images.length);

            }

            document.getElementById('newImage').src = images[rand];
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="image1.jpg" id="bigPic" style="width:60%" />
        </div>
            <img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" onclick="changeImage(0)"  />
            <img src="image2.jpg" id="img2" onclick="changeImage(1)" />
            <img src="image3.jpg" id="img3" onclick="changeImage(2)" />
            <img src="image4.jpg" id="img4" onclick="changeImage(3)"  />

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some learning to do... there's a lot of things wrong with your code:

1. a div in the head?
2. forgot a " in images array
3. overwriting param in changeImage is not a good idea
4. using () in setInterval will call the function immediately, and only once
5. chose() doesn't do anything
6. array index is 0-based (0-3 for images array) but you're rounding up your random number (1-4)

Open your browser console and check for errors.

You probably need something like this (not tested):

```
  <script>
      var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];

      function changeImage( idx ) {
          var newImage = document.getElementById("bigPic");
          newImage.src = images[idx];
      }

      function chose(){
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
          changeImage(rand);
      }

      chose(); // call immediately
      var myTimer = setInterval(chose, 3000);
  </script>
```